<section> or <article> as containers of Angular components for Accessibility and/or SEO purposes?
I’m working on an Angular project and want to ensure that my components follow HTML semantics for both Accessibility and SEO purposes, but only when is need because I don't want to add extra code.
Using tags like <section> and <article> doesn't seem critical for:

Accessibility: Screen readers and assistive technologies primarily rely on content, headings, and other semantic tags like lists or links to convey meaning.
Semantics within Angular: The component selector itself provide enough context about the content's purpose.

In this case, using <section> and <article> tags seems more useful for SEO purposes to help search engines better understand the content structure.
In case I need to use a semantic tag to wrap a product-card, I have discovered that I can limit its purpose using:
selector: 'article [app-product-card]'


It's unclear what your question is. Proper usage of <section> and <article> is an important part of accessibility.

Why are important?

While not as popular and used as navigation by heading, navigation by landmark is still very important for screen reader and other assistive tool users. You shouldn't neglect what <section> and <article> bring for accessibility.

But for example  only becomes a landmark when it has been given an accessible name using aria-labelledby or aria-label – see Labelling landmarks below.

 is not a landmark, right? https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/landmarks/HTML5.html
Yes, <article> is a landmark. At least with Jaws and NVDA.

Article: for informative short or large chunks of "info" related to or about/referencing something in or outside of current site individually. "section" or "aside" can be used in separate instances not defined as similar to in usage as mentioned above for the "article". So an example would be, wanting to reference a book and including author for crediting purposes only, the author and there content(outside of this ref) is unrelated to content held on site and used for ref only. "article" would be good for this scenario. If it's more relative to content in site "aside" or "section" would be good. EDIT: seems was more geared towards SEO & Accessibility implications specifically, and to answer that none of the above are going to improve seo ranking over other as both doesn't affect it, for accessibility just proper and non redundant attributes in the element is best regardless of tags used, hope that answers question.

Thanks for the response. I understand the semantic purpose — the MDN Web Docs are clear on that. However, my question is more related to accessibility or SEO purposes.
Wrapping a selector like a product-card component with an  tag doesn't make it more semantic, but for example, ¿has an accessibility relevant impact?

This is not what an <article> element is for. Please refer to the usage guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

The  HTML element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication). Examples include: a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry, a product card, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.
A product-card cound be an article

Updated post...

"Article: for informative short or large chunks of text related to or about/referencing something in or outside of current site once." This is not what an article element is for.
